# How can I parse in memory strings (of type String) in OCaml using ocamlyacc?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I have a parser which parses the std input using Ocamlyacc and lex. How can I trigger the start parse rule on a string in OCaml?

Comment: What does your code look like? The part that calls your lexer on standard input?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to answer but assuming your start rule is called `start`, and your generated parser module is called `Parser.ml` and yout generated lexer module is called `Lexer.ml`, you should do something like :

```
let parse_from_string s =
  let lex = Lexing.from_string s in
    try
      Lexing.(lex.lex_curr_p <- {lex.lex_curr_p with pos_cnum = 0});
      Parser.start Lexer.token lex
    with
    | Failure s ->
        Printf.eprintf "Error near %s\n\n"
        (string_of_position lex.lex_start_p)
```